# Is there a canonical way to transform Filter.Criteria to a query string in GmailApi?

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I'm building an app that uses the Gmail API to get the user's filters, and then uses the `Filter.Criteria` to search for emails that would be matched by the filter.

e.g. Filter [[reference]](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters):

```
{
  id: 'id',
  criteria: {from:'foo@bar.baz', subject:'whatever', ...},
  actions: {...},
}
```

However the API's `user.messages.list` method can only filter with a `q` param that's a string that looks like something you would type on gmail's search box using these operators: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en

e.g. Query string:

```
from:(foo@bar.baz) subject:(whatever)
```

My problem is that I'm supposed to transform the `Filter` into a string that can be used for `q`, but it's not completely straightforward because there are some special cases that I have to find with trial and error.

I'd like to know if there's a canonical way to do this or whether I have to implement the transformation myself.

Comment: @DaImTo I believe you retaliated with a -1 because I -1d your offtopic answer and deleted it. If I'm not correct, could you at least leave a reason why the -1 (helps ppl grow when you give critical feedback)

Comment: Gmail isn't mentioned until the last paragraph, and in the tags. Someone starting to read this question doesn't get the full context of what you are getting at until then. Providing examples of q params and filter params might be useful for context as well.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I've updated the question